# add multiple documents to a collection

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I need to add multiple objects (Documents) inside a collection, but I do not want to update my Observable whenever I add a new record.

Can I do this by traversing a list of objects to insert?

I would like to display a loading from which the records are being run and inserted into the database, and after all have been entered there yes I update my Observable.

Is there a way to do this? What is the most correct way to insert multiple objects into a Cloud Firestore collation?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export interface Item { name: string; }

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let item of items | async">
        {{ item.name }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  private itemsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Item>;
  items: Observable<Item[]>;
  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.itemsCollection = afs.collection<Item>('items');
    this.items = this.itemsCollection.valueChanges();
  }

  addItem(item: Item) {
    this.itemsCollection.add(item);
  }

  addItems(listItem: Item[]) {
       // Is it the right way to do it?
       for (let item of listItem) {
          this.itemsCollection.add(item);
       }
  }

}
```

Comment: Do you tried [batched writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes)?

Comment: How can I do that? I think I saw something you're talking about but I do not know how to do it using [angularfire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2)

Comment: Something [like that](https://gist.github.com/olshansky/69d3dd3b8dbf0f27d1700a8bcaa0afe0)

Comment: Okay, so it will only update the Observable items when doing the commit? Or will I update the Observable whenever I call add () method?

Comment: Should be updated after commit, but I'm not completely sure. Try it ;)